# Can I optimize my verilog code using Synopsys DC and bring it back to Xilinx

Tags: optimization, verilog

I would like to know if it is possible to optimize existing verilog code in Synopsys DC and use the optimized gate level code in Xilinx to use in my FPGA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming you have the right Xilinx gate-level library for DC.

Comment: I don't think any such libs exist although I could be wrong.  Synopsys would surely point you towards Synplify for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think it won’t be possible to get library

Comment: As Brian mentioned Synplify is the only way, this is also confirmed by a Synopsys trainer today.